# $0<a_n<\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2} \Longrightarrow a_n\ $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$$a_n<\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$$
Show that $a_n$ converges.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem so far? Information like this will help us to determine what tools you have available, and what your level of skill/exposure/comprehension is, so that we can better tailor our answer to your needs.

Comment: @Cameron Buie: It's not homework, just a slightly less conventional problem on the topic of convergence of sequences. I tried to show the sequence was Cauchy but I had some problems with absolute values and I didn't manage to.

Comment: Try showing it is falling monotonously. As it is a series of positive reals, it is bounded. So that suffices.

Comment: @Louis: Are you sure it is always monotonic decreasing, at least ultimately?

Comment: You're right, it's not.

Comment: You have a contractive sequence which can prove that $a_n$ converges.

Comment: @user60887 "contractive sequence" Meaning?

Comment: @user60887: Why is $a_n$ contractive? You can deduce that $a_n-a_{n-1}<\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-2}-a_{n-1})$ but I don't see how this implies that $|a_n-a_{n-1}|<\frac{1}{2}|a_{n-2}-a_{n-1}|$.

Comment: @Did: $a_n$ is said to be contractive if there exists a constant $C$ such that $0<C<1$ and $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq C|a_{n+1}-{a_n}|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or at least ultimately).

Comment: @AdrianoMeis I know, thanks. My point was to lead the OP to wonder whether this was an obvious fact that this sequence is (it is not).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the sequence given by $b_n := \max (a_{n-1},a_{n-2})$. Now, $a_n ≤ b_n$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$, and $(b_n)$ is monotonically nonincreasing, because
$$b_{n+1} = \max (a_n,a_{n-1}) ≤ \max(b_n, a_{n-1}) = b_n.$$
Since $(b_n)$ is nonnegative nonincreasing, it has to converge and therefore so does $(a_n)$, since we can sandwich.

This argument is incomplete, as pointed out in the comments: What is the other part of the sandwich? However, Did did complete the argument in the comments.

Comment: "since we can sandwich" One side is clear but you might want to expand on the other side of the sandwich.

Comment: I presume you mean with $c_n=min(a_{n-1},a_{n-2})$? this converges, as the same argument (neat, by the way!) goes through. but do $b_n$ and $c_n$ converge to the same value?

Comment: @DavidHolden – And this is nontrivial! I thought, it was. Good point, thanks to you and Did.

Comment: on reflection I think my reasoning is faulty, as the problem is asymmetric and we don't have $a_n \ge c_n$

Comment: You lost me: do you consider that your solution is complete, or not?

Comment: @Did I do not consider it to be complete.

Comment: Then consider this: one knows that $b_n\to\ell$ and that $b_n\geqslant\ell$ for every $n$, thus $b_n\leqslant\ell+\varepsilon$ for every $n\geqslant N$, and $a_n\leqslant\ell+\varepsilon$ for every $n\geqslant N$. Assume that $a_n\leqslant\ell-3\varepsilon$ for some $n\geqslant N+1$, then $a_{n+1}\leqslant\frac12(\ell+\varepsilon+\ell-3\varepsilon)=\ell-\varepsilon$ hence $b_{n+2}\leqslant\ell-\varepsilon$, which is absurd. Thus $\ell-3\varepsilon\leqslant a_n\leqslant\ell+\varepsilon$ for every $n\geqslant N+1$, QED.

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks, @Did.

Comment: hats off to Did! rather a tricky little question!

Answer (score 1):

the following line of reasoning may be a step towards a solution:

with a slight change of notation, define $s_0=a_0$ and for $n \ge 1$ let $s_n=a_n+\frac12 a_{n-1}$. the question is now: if $\{s_k\}$ is a convergent, decreasing sequence of non-negative reals, does the sequence $\{a_k\}$ converge?

describe the sequences up to their $n$-th terms as $n+1$-vectors $S_n$ and $A_n$. then we can define a sequence of square matrices $Q_n$, such that:
$$ S_n = Q_n A_n
$$
here, obviously, $Q_0$ is just the scalar value $1$, and each subsequent $Q_n$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose diagonal elements are all $1$, and whose only other non-zero entries are $q_{i+1,i}=\frac12$, for $i=0,\dots,n-1$.

the matrices $Q_n$ are nonsingular, with inverses $Q_n^{-1}$, whose elements are given by (NB subscripts range from $0$ to $n$)
$$ q_{ij}^{-1}= \left( \frac{-1}{2} \right)^{j-i}
$$ for $i \ge j$ and zero otherwise. this gives:
$$
a_n = s_n - \frac12 s_{n-1} + \frac14 s_{n-2} -\dots + \left( \frac{-1}{2} \right)^n s_0
$$
if the limit of the sequence $s_n$ is $\lambda$ then:
$$
a_n - \frac23 \lambda = \sum_{k=0}^n (s_{n-k}-\lambda) \left(\frac{-1}2\right)^k \\
=  \sum_{k=0}^{n-N} (s_{n-k}-\lambda) \left(\frac{-1}2\right)^k +\left(\frac{-1}2\right)^{n-N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(s_{n-N+k}-\lambda)\left(\frac{-1}2\right)^k
$$

Comment: +1. Now we have two proofs, both based on some auxiliary nonnegative nonincreasing sequence,  $b_n=\max(a_n,a_{n-1})$ or $s_n=a_n+\frac12a_{n-1}$, both requiring an extra argument to "come back" from the convergence of this auxiliary sequence to the convergence of $(a_n)$. This is nice.

Comment: @Did thanks for the encouragement. still not quite nailed it, but have just added another line which takes it along a bit. it appears that the limit of the $a_n$ will be $\frac23$ of the limit of the $s_n$ which if the limit exists, on account of the strange "knight's move" definition of $s_n$. this is obvious now I think of it, but uncertainty saps confidence, and inclines one to miss things. I think by now the pleasure (and instruction) I have had from this exercise is outweighing the initial pain of puzzlement and frustration.

Comment: If $s_n\to s$ and $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}/2+\cdots+(-1)^ns_0/2^n$ as in your answer then $a_n\to2s/3$. This is elementary epsilon-delta analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The same holds for a **nonlinear** average as the upper bound on $a_n$.

Suppose that $a_n \leq f(a_{n-1},a_{n-2}, \dots, a_{n-k})$ for a generalized mean $f$, which for this answer means:

- $f(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is increasing in all its variables, and continuous
- $f(a,a,a,\dots,a)=a$ for all $a$
- $f$ has *finite velocity*, defined here to mean that $\partial f / \partial{x_i} \geq c > 0$ for a constant $c$ and all $i=1,2,...,k$

(It is not assumed that $f$ is symmetric in its variables, or differentiable. The finite velocity condition is stated with derivatives only to simplify notation.)

Then: if the sequence $a_n$ is bounded below, it converges.

Proof.

1) $m_n = \max(a_{n},a_{n+1},\dots a_{n+k-1})$ satisfies $m_n \geq m_{n+k}$

2) sequence $m_{kn}+r$ has a limit $M_r$ for any integer $r$ and $n \to \infty$, because it is decreasing and bounded below

3) there are a finite number of values of $M_r$, which is a periodic function of $r$ with period $k$, but they are all equal, because the largest $M_r$, call it $\mathbb{M}$, must (by finite velocity) come from maxima of consecutive $k$-tuples $(a_i, a_{i+1}, \dots, a_{i+k-1})$ that are infinitesimally close to $\mathbb{M}$; then the next $k$ values ($a_{i+k}$ to $a_{i + 2k-1}$) are also (by continuity of $f$) close to $\mathbb{M}$, and a block of $2k$ values infinitesimally close to $\mathbb{M}$ means that all $M_r$ are also at least that close to $\mathbb{M}$ (by generalized mean, $f$ is between the min and max of its arguments), hence equal.

4) For large $n$ the $a_n$ converge to $\mathbb{M}$, since this is the case on the progressions $n = r \mod k$ (or repeat the same argument as in (3), taking blocks of $k$ terms whose maxima are close to $\mathbb{M}$).

The essential point is that finite velocity rules out oscillations between different limiting values on the subsequences, as would happen with $f(x,y)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

does the following approach lead anywhere? we have $$ a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_n}{2} - \epsilon_n$$
where $0 \lt \epsilon_n \lt \frac{a_{n+1}+a_n}{2}$.  so by adding,
$$  a_{n+2}+a_{n+1} - a_1-a_0 = \frac12 (a_{n+1} - a_0) - \sum_{k=0}^n \epsilon_k
$$ or
$$ a_{n+2}+\frac12 a_{n+1} = a_1+\frac12 a_0 - \sum_{k=0}^n \epsilon_k
$$ defining:
$$s_{n+1} = a_{n+2} +\frac12 a_{n+1}$$
this becomes
$$s_{n+1} = s_0 - \sum_{k=0}^n \epsilon_k
$$
which guarantees convergence of $s_n$

Comment: This nicely shows that $s_n$ converges. How to come back to $a_n$?

Comment: @Did exactly! delightfully irritating problem and I would like to understand why. so I thought my modicum of progress worth noting, despite the presence of your excellent demonstration.

Comment: @K.Stm.'s one, you mean. As I said, your approach looks nice, and it would be interesting to bypass the use of $\max(a_n,a_{n-1})$.

Comment: @Did, the answer to the generalized problem, posted a few minutes ago, suggests that $\max(a_n, a_{n-1})$ is in some way essential to the problem, and can be bypassed only if the solution method is tied to the very specific form of the upper bound.  We do see this in the solutions that rely on the 2nd order linear recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Set $$b_n=a_n+\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}$$ for $n\geq2.$ Then, $\{b_n\}_{n\geq2}$ is a positive sequence satisfying $$b_n<b_{n-1}$$ for $n\geq3.$ Thus, $\{b_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. In other words, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}\right)=b\geq0,$$ which implies that $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, and so $$a:=\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\in\mathbf R\ \text{and}\ A:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\in\mathbf R.$$ Then, $$A+\frac{a}{2}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n+\frac{1}{2}\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n+\frac{1}{2}\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=a+\frac{A}{2},$$ which gives that $A\leq a,$ and so $A=a.$

**Basic Fact.** For two bounded sequences $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$, we have \begin{align*}&\liminf u_n+\liminf v_n\\\leq&\liminf(u_n+v_n)\\\leq&\liminf u_n+\limsup v_n\\\leq&\limsup(u_n+v_n)\\\leq&\limsup u_n+\limsup v_n.\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded between $\ \max \{a_1,a_2\} $ and $0.$ Therefore by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $\ (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ has at least one limit (accumulation) point in the interval$\ [\ 0,\ \max \{a_1,a_2\}\ ].$

Now suppose, by way of contradiction, that $\ (a_n)\ $ has at least two limit points, $\ l_1\ $ and $\ l_2,\ $ with $\ l_1<l_2.\ $

*Lemma*: If  $\ a_{n+1} > a_n,\ $ then $\ a_k < a_n + \frac{3}{4}\left( a_{n+1} -a_n\right)\quad \forall\ k\geq n+2.$

Next, since $\ l_1\ $ and $\ l_2\ $ are limit points, $\ \exists\ N_1\ $ such that, $\ a_{N_1} < \frac{l_1+l_2}{2},\ $ and $\ a_{N_1 + 1} > \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}.\ $ The Lemma implies then that:

$$\ a_k < a_{N_1} + \frac{3}{4}\left( a_{N_1+1} -a_{N_1}\right) \leq \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} + \frac{3}{4}\left( a_{N_1+1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}\right)$$

$$\implies a_k - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} < \frac{3}{4}\left( a_{N_1+1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}\right)  \quad \forall\ k\geq N_1+2.\quad (1) $$

Continuing, $\ \exists\ N_2>N_1+2\ $ such that, $\ a_{N_2} < \frac{l_1+l_2}{2},\ $ and $\ a_{N_2 + 1} > \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}.\ $ Since $\ N_2 > N_1 + 2,\ $ all $\ k\geq N_2\ $ satisfies $\ (1)\ $ also. Thus,

$$ a_k - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} < \frac{3}{4}\left( a_{N_2+1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}\right) < \frac{3}{4}\left( \frac{3}{4} \left( a_{N_1+1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}\right) \right) = \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^2 \left( a_{N_1+1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2}\right) $$

$$ \quad \forall\ k\geq N_2+2.\quad (2) $$

Continuing in this way, we can find and increasing sequence of integers $\ (n_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ such that for each $\ j,\ $ we have:

$$ a_k \leq \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j \left( a_{N_1 + 1} - \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} \right)\quad \forall\ k\geq N_j + 2. $$

But then, since $\  \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j \to 0,\ $ as $\ j\to\infty,\ $ it follows that $\ \displaystyle\limsup_k\ a_k\ \leq \frac{l_1+l_2}{2} $ contradicting the fact that $\ l_2\ $ is a limit point of $\ (a_n)_n.$

$$$$

I have left the proof of the lemma, and a couple of other details as an exercise to the reader, but these things should be relatively straightforward.